# Does EsLint have a rule to prefer Object values as key and value?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Looking for a rule(can't seem to find anything, might've just missed it) in [EsLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) to basically prefer something like this:

```
const example = {
    foo,
    bar
};
```

vs something like this:

```
const example = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the rule [object-shorthand](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand):

> Requires or disallows method and property shorthand syntax for object literals.

It will work fine with the default settings. You can test it in [this demo](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyogZXNsaW50IG9iamVjdC1zaG9ydGhhbmQ6IFwiZXJyb3JcIiAqL1xuY29uc3QgZXhhbXBsZSA9IHtcbiAgICBmb286IGZvbyxcbiAgICBiYXI6IGJhclxufTsiLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7InBhcnNlck9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZWNtYVZlcnNpb24iOiJsYXRlc3QiLCJzb3VyY2VUeXBlIjoibW9kdWxlIiwiZWNtYUZlYXR1cmVzIjp7fX0sInJ1bGVzIjp7fSwiZW52Ijp7fX19).